# Не получается докрутить сложный MySQL-запрос

Tags: mysql, запрос, join

```
SELECT ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id,
(IFNULL(SUM(ad.qty),0)+IFNULL(b.move_qty,0)) as qty, SUM(ad.qty) as 
arrival_qty, b.move_qty as movement_qty, a.warehouse_id FROM arrival_data ad
LEFT JOIN arrivals a 
 ON ad.arrival_id = a.arrival_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(m.qty) as move_qty, m.size_id, m.height_id, 
m.spec_id, mb.receiver FROM movement_data m, movements mb 
WHERE mb.movement_id = m.movement_id GROUP BY m.size_id, m.height_id, m.spec_id, 
mb.receiver) b
ON ad.size_id= b.size_id 
    AND ad.height_id = b.height_id 
    AND ad.spec_id = b.spec_id
    AND b.receiver = a.warehouse_id             

GROUP BY ad.spec_id, ad.size_id, ad.height_id, a.warehouse_id
```

Запрос должен брать товар по трем характеристикам уникальности из двух таблиц приходы и перемещения, суммировать количество в каждой. И создавать общее количество по каждому приход+перемещение на этот склад и группировать по складам. Запрос работает но выдает только один склад на который есть приходы. Склады где только перемещения а приходов нет не отображает. Буду благодарен кто вникнет и поможет

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/074bf/3

Comment: "sql-запрос, который ты видишь, когда попадаешь в ад", ну там их вечность, конечно же.

Comment: я посоветовал бы, вынесити дублирующиеся `spec_id INT(10), size_id INT(10), height_id INT(10)` в отдельную таблицу `Goods`, потом просто группировать по ID товара (конечно если ещё не поздно).

Comment: @strangeqargo Видимо я живу в аду, ну или вы в раю. Ибо запросы по 5 страниц текста с 15+ таблицами в них считаются обычным делом.

Comment: @Mike я не про размер, а про качество

Comment: Не вижу вашей полной структуры, но мне кажется, что поступления на склад очень похожи на перемещения, только это "перемещение снаружи". И тогда напрашивается держать их в одних таблицах. И какие нибудь списания со склада (которые у вас то же наверняка есть) напрашиваются туда же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В примере у вас очень странные данные, в arrivals нет записи с ID 22, но данные с таким ID есть в arrivals_data. Ваш LEFT в запросе конечно нивелирует это, но на выходе получаем записи с NULL складом. Я исхожу из того, что это просто ошибка и такого в реальной БД быть не может (кстати, где в таблицах foreign key, которые помогают избежать несогласованности данных ?).

А беда запроса в том, что LEFT JOIN считает необязательными данные только справа от оператора, но не слева. И когда слева данных нет - то и на выходе нет. В данном случае мог бы помочь FULL OUTER JOIN, но по несчастливой случайности MySQL его не поддерживает. Поэтому к запросу надо подойти совсем с другой стороны, вместо join воспользоваться суммированием и группировкой, заранее приведенных к одной структуре, данных:

```
select spec_id, size_id, height_id,
       ifnull(sum(arrival_qty),0)+ifnull(sum(move_qty),0) as qty,
       sum(arrival_qty) as arrival_qty,
       sum(move_qty)    as movement_qty,
       warehouse_id
  from (
        select warehouse_id, spec_id, size_id, height_id, qty as arrival_qty,
               NULL as move_qty
          from arrival_data ad, arrivals a
         where a.arrival_id=ad.arrival_id
        union all
        select mb.receiver, m.spec_id, m.size_id, m.height_id, NULL, m.qty as move_qty
          from movement_data m, movements mb 
         where mb.movement_id = m.movement_id 
       ) A
 group by spec_id, size_id, height_id, warehouse_id
```

Comment: данные засунул в пример наспех.. конечно без arrivals id не может быть в arrival_data. сейчас попробую ваш вариант

Comment: ну склады показывает все.. Сейчас попробую выборочно сверить верность данных..Итак получается мы сначала юнионом собираем со всех таблиц в единую структуру как я понимаю а потом уже суммируем то что получается.. и создаем нулевое поле. хм.. тоесть если 4 таблицы то 4 таких поля нужно создать. И на последок вопрос! Правильней было бы структуру БД делать одну таблицу на все движения или то что приходы, расходы и перемещения в разных это нормально?

Comment: _кстати, где в таблицах foreign key, которые помогают избежать несогласованности данных ?)._ Эта матчасть еще не изучена. Чем и займусь не отходя от кассы.

Comment: @Durrasell Кстати, если вам NULL не принципиален, можно делать поле 0 и тогда вам ifnull не понадобятся. Я оставил NULL что бы до группировки было видно откуда данные пришли. Посмотрите мой последний коммент под вашим вопросом, я там как раз пишу, что все виды движения возможно стоит держать в одной таблице.

Comment: Ну работает как надо. я уже добавляю туда еще два движения перемещения аут и расходы.. Ну вы конечно и нинздя. Очень хочется верить, что когда-нить так же буду знать матчасть. Спасибо большое